# Overloading Properties

Tags: vba, syntax, properties, vb6, overloading

I tried to overload in VBA within a class module:

```
Dim a As Integer

Public Property Let SomeNumber(newNumber as Integer)
   a = newNumber
End Property
Public Property Let SomeNumber(newNumber as String)
   a = Val(newNumber)
End Property
Public Property Get SomeNumber() As Integer
   SomeNumber = a
End Property
```

The compiler complains that an "ambiguous name was detected" where clearly there is a different signature. Is it possible to overload a property defined within a class in VBA or VB6?  If so, what would be the syntax?

Moreover, if property overloading is not possible, what benefits do properties offer over get/set methods defined by public functions other than a more seamless way to access the fields of an instantiated object?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't, but I'll let someone who's 100% sure answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see here:

http://vbcity.com/forums/t/76453.aspx

It seems you are out of luck until you convert to VB.NET.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use a variant or object type  and manually handle the type checking?

A mixture of Optional parameters may also be possible, but it's not exactly equivalent to overloading either.

Answer (score 2):

No.

The workaround is to use Variants, which allows the client to pass anything. But you have to write code to do the type-checking at runtime:

```
Public Property Let SomeNumber(newNumber as Variant)
   Select Case VarType(newNumber) 
      Case vbInteger         '' Caller passed an integer
        a = newNumber
      Case vbString          '' Caller passed a string
        a = Val(newNumber)
      Case Else
        Err.Raise vbObjectError+513, , "Invalid type passed"
      End Select
End Property
Public Property Get SomeNumber() As Variant
   SomeNumber = a
End Property
```

For more details see Dan Appleman's excellent book [Developing COM/ActiveX Components In Visual Basic 6](http://Developing%20COM/ActiveX%20Components%20In%20Visual%20Basic%206).

Answer (score 1):

There was a thread on this topic:

[Function Overloading and UDF in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64436/function-overloading-in-excel-vba)

Comment: This is a similar thread, but not quite what I was looking for.  Still good insight thought.