# Access VBA object types

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to build a procedure in my Access project that will accept either a table or a form as part of the argument. If the object is a table then it should check the table's fields; if it's a form then it should it the form's controls.

I've tried using either variant or object variable types for the argument. But either way when I check the VarType() the passed variable is of type object, so I can't distinguish between them. (I'm currently passing a table as a TableDef object by the way.)

I would try overloading the function based on parameter type but apparently that isn't available in VBA (as far as I know from [Function Overloading and UDF in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64436/function-overloading-and-udf-in-excel-vba). Any suggestions?

Comment: *"either a table or a form as part of the argument"*  How do you pass a table to your procedure?  As a string for the table name?  As a `TableDef` or recordset object?

Comment: Try `TypeName()` instead

Comment: You can look it up in MSysObjects and use an If/Then statement to run the correct procedure.  Forms have a MSysObjects.Type=-32768, and Tables have a MSysObjects.Type=1, 4 or 6 (depending on if they're local or linked).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test for a certain class in VBA, use a combination of the `TypeOf` and `Is` operators:

```
Sub WishVBAHadOverloads(ByVal Obj As Object)
  If TypeOf Obj Is TableDef Then 
    Dim Def As TableDef
    Set Def = Obj
    ' work with Def... 
    Exit Sub
  End If
  If TypeOf Obj Is Form Then 
    Dim Frm As Form
    Set Frm = Obj
    ' work with Frm... 
    Exit Sub
  End If
  Err.Raise 999, "WishVBAHadOverloads", "Bad argument type - expected a TableDef or Form"
End Sub
```

Comment: TypeOf ... Is does seem to work. Helpful and clever  -- "WishVBAHadOverloads"! 8^)