# Passing object types in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I would like to pass the type of MS Access objects to a function. From an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20664923/access-vba-object-types) I know that you can test for TableDef, form, QueryDef, etc. types using *TypeOf... is*. But I do not know what the types of the results are and how to pass them to a new function that doesn't have access to the original object.

I'd like to be able to pass something like CStr(TypeOf(*object*)) but TypeOf doesn't seem to be able to be called outside of the TypeOf... is statement.

I guess I could create a helper function that tests for object types I'm interested in and returns a string or enum. But if someone knows how to pass the object type, that would be a lot simpler!

Comment: What is an example of how you'd need this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is already an enum for Access object types: the acObjectType enumeration, described on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845495%28v=office.15%29.aspx). This is used, for example, in the application.sethiddenattribute method. Unfortunately I only found this after creating my own enum for a different procedure I was writing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm unsure exactly what you want, but wonder whether `TypeName()` might be useful.

Here are a few examples from an Immediate window session:

```vb
? TypeName(CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblFoo"))
TableDef

? TypeName(CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryFoo"))
QueryDef

DoCmd.OpenForm "Form3"
? TypeName(Forms!Form3)
Form_Form3

? TypeName(Forms!Form3!cboUserId)
ComboBox
```

Comment: That does seem promising. But it does seem like the returned string for a form is strange, like form_<formname>. I guess I could truncate that? Also, TypeName returns logical responses from code, but from the immediate window it keeps returning "empty" for any of the DAO objects I use. And it doesn't seem to be able to test any form that isn't currently open?

Comment: Right, I wondered whether `Form_Form3` would be a concern.  You would face a similar issue with a report object: `Report_rptFoo`.  Perhaps you could do `If TypeName(object) Like "Form_*" Then`  Or create a custom function which uses `TypeOf` to first check whether the object is a form or report, and otherwise use `TypeName`.

Comment: I don't get "empty" for a recordset which is currently open.  So I don't understand that one.  However, I also should disclose this is new territory for me.

Comment: I puzzled by the issue of identifying a form as a form when it's not open.  In that case do you have the form name as a string value and you want to determine that string represents the name of a form?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to be able to retrieve information from a form without necessarily opening it.

Comment: When you give Access a string, it has no way to know that string contains the name of a form.  Check whether it exists in `CurrentProject.AllForms` if you want to know whether it is the name of a form.  Check `CurrentProject.AllReports` to see whether it is the name of a report.  And so forth ...

Comment: I have a function to check if an object exists in the DB by name. It loops over the TableDefs, QueryDefs, Forms, and Reports and compares the parameter name to the name of each object. But I need the function to receive the type of the object so it knows which collection to check (you can have a table, form, etc. with the same name as long as the type is different).

Comment: Sorry, but I suspect I'm missing something which may be obvious to you and everyone else.  When you find your target name in the forms collection, you know that target name is a form.  So use that same collection loop/searching strategy to determine the object type of the target name.  Where is the problem?

Comment: " When you find your target name in the forms collection, you know that target name is a form." Not really. As I alluded to, you can have a table, a form, a query, and a report that are all named "Hans." So you know that there _is_ a form with that name if you find it in that collection, but there may _also_ be another object type with the same name. So I want to be able to be explicit.

Comment: I tried to invite you to a chat but the system says you don't have enough rep.  So I will just withdraw from this because it's now clear to me that I don't have enough of a clue to actually help you.  Good luck.